# Pandas display all index labels in jupyter notebook despite repetition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

When displaying a DataFrame in jupyter notebook. The index is displayed in a hierarchical way. So that repeated labels are not shown in the following row. E.g. a dataframe with a Multiindex with the following labels

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
```

will be displayed as

```
1 1 1 1 ...
    0 1 ...
```

Can I change this behaviour so that all index values are shown despite repetition? Like this:

```
1 1 1 1 ...
1 1 0 1 ...
```

?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
N_t = 5
N_e = 2
classes = tuple(list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=N_e)))
N_c = len(classes)
noise = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(N_c, N_t))
df = pd.DataFrame(noise, index=classes)
df

        0   1   2   3   4
0   0   5   9   4   1   2
    1   2   2   7   9   9
1   0   1   7   3   6   9
    1   4   9   8   2   9

# should be shown as
        0   1   2   3   4
0   0   5   9   4   1   2
0   1   2   2   7   9   9
1   0   1   7   3   6   9
1   1   4   9   8   2   9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
```

**Output**

```
     0  1  2  3  4
0 0  8  1  4  0  2
0 1  0  1  7  4  7
1 0  9  6  5  2  0
1 1  2  2  7  2  7
```

And  globally:

```
pd.options.display.multi_sparse = False
```

**or**

thanks @Kyle -

```
print(df.to_string(sparsify=False))
```

Comment: You can do it just for the single print via `print(df.to_string(sparsify=false)`